# Can't calling the Web Service's method in the same solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-services

In my solution,I create a console project at first and then create another web service project with one service method,I want to use the service method of the service project,so I added the web service reference to the console project,but when I calling the service method in the console project,it always alert me that 'target computer actively reject'.

someone said that's the problem of port.

here is the code of Setting.Designer.cs file:

```
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "16.1.0.0")]
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default {
        get {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(global::System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.WebServiceUrl)]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("https://localhost:44321/ExtractName.asmx")]
    public string SystemClass_iCloudExtract_ExtractName {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["SystemClass_iCloudExtract_ExtractName"]));
        }
    }
}
```

here is the code of console project's app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="SystemClass.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" publicKeyToken="71e9bce111e9429c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <applicationSettings>
    <SystemClass.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="SystemClass_iCloudExtract_ExtractName" serializeAs="String">
        <value>https://localhost:44321/Extractame.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </SystemClass.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

the error is 'target computer actively reject'.

Comment: You seem to be running your webserver locally, but the webserver rejects the request you're making with your console app. Have a look at your server's log files maybe ?

Comment: sorry,I found that it has no log about this project.